# Returning References from Struct Method with Lifetimes

Tags: rust

I am trying this code:

```
struct ByteIter<'a> {
    remainder: &'a mut [u8],
    index: usize,
}

impl<'a> ByteIter<'a> {
    fn new(remainder: &'a mut [u8]) -> ByteIter<'a> {
        ByteIter{remainder, index: 0}
    }

    fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a mut u8> {
        if self.index >= self.remainder.len() {
            None
        } else {
            let mut byte = &mut self.remainder[self.index];
            self.index  += 1;
            Some(byte)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = [ 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54];
    let mut bytes = ByteIter::new(&mut a);
    {
        let byte_1 = bytes.next();
    }
    let byte_2 = bytes.next();

}
```

Now, as I understand, the `byte_1` was borrowed from bytes. But it's lifetime has already expired. Still when I compile this, I see the following error:

```
29 |     let byte_2 = bytes.next();
   |                  ^^^^^
   |                  |
   |                  second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                  first borrow later used here
```

What is the first mutable borrow here? Shouldn't it be released when byte_1 goes out of scope?

Importantly, what should I do to fix this?

Comment: By the way you don't check if `self.index` is out of bounds of the slice

Comment: Ah, a leftover, as I tried to strip the problem to its bare minimal. Fixed!

Comment: Look at [this thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/iterator-lifetime-error-only-when-using-a-mutable-reference/50460). The pattern you try to use is pretty common, but I think it can't be implemented without `unsafe`. The underlying reason is that you have your data `a`, you have a mutable reference to it inside your iterator, and you have a mutable reference to `a` again, when you try to return a single element by a mutable reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `impl<'a> ByteIter<'a>`, you declare that `'a` is the lifetime used in the structure, ie, it's the lifetime of the underlying slice.

Now, when you say `fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a mut u8> {`, you're reusing the same `'a`, and you say it's the same than the returned mutable reference. You're saying that the returned lifetime is the same than the `ByteIter` struct content.

Remove the additional lifetime constraint and the compiler will be free to compute the appropriate lifetime:

```rust
fn next(& mut self) -> Option<& mut u8> {
    if self.index >= self.remainder.len() {
        None
    } else {
        let mut byte = &mut self.remainder[self.index];
        self.index  += 1;
        Some(byte)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, this does work. What I don't understand is that as per the 3rd lifetime elision rule: the lifetime of the `&mut self` will be assigned to all output parameters. 

If so, how is it different from the code in the problem statement? Because it doesn't match the `'a` in the structure's lifetime?

Comment: The lifetime elision rules mean that the elided code is equivalent to `fn next<'b> (&'b mut self) -> Option<&'b mut u8>` with the `'b` lifetime allowed to be different from `'a`.

Comment: @kscos I edited to try to be clearer. Be careful not to confuse the reference to the structure and the reference from the structure to the underlying data. They have no reason to be the same.

Comment: Got it, that was the source of confusion for me. Assuming that `&'b mut self` and `ByteIterator<'a>` have the same lifetimes :+1: